# Combinatorial Proof help for solving $\pi_n$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> For $n\ge1$, $\pi_n=n\pi_{n-1}+1$

I have to give a combinatorial proof. I am not sure as into what direction to start this. help? suggestions?

for clarification:
$\pi_n$ equals the number of permutations of $[n]$ having any length, including $0$ (the "empty permutation").

for instance,

$\pi_1 = 2$ 
because it includes the sets $\emptyset, (1)$

$\pi_2 = 5$ 
because it includes the sets $\emptyset, (1), (2), (1,2), (2,1)$

Comment: $\pi_1=1$, $\pi_2=2$ so...

Comment: What does the square brackets in $[n]$ mean?

Comment: @JesterTran: I this context I would assume that $[n]$ means $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Note:  as suggested by @HenningMakholm, and as indicated by the examples given, the word "permutation" is being used incorrectly here.  The OP appears to mean "any ordered list of distinct elements chosen from $\{0,1,\cdots, n\}$

Comment: Typo:  in my previous comment, I meant to write $\{1,\cdots, n\}$, $0$ should not have been included.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by "permutation of $A$" you mean a list of elements of $A$ where no element appears twice. (This is different from the usual meaning of "permutation" which is a bijective function $A\to A$).

Then: Any "permutation" of $[n]$ is either the empty "permutation", or you can make it by choosing one of the $n$ elements to be first and appending any "permutation" of the $n-1$ remaining elements.